# ListView is legacy in Android Studio 5 and I am trying to do scrollable list so what to use?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I have been reading ListView is Scrollable and ScrollView is scrollable and you don't really want to put them together.  Also, ListView is legacy (which I think means deprecated) in Android Studio 4.  I am a complete newb so if I ask this question wrong, it's because I don't yet have enough knowledge to ask the right question.

I would like to do a list of contacts that is scrollable so I would think I want a ScrollView + some kind of list but that piece I am not sure of.  What should I combine ScrollView with?  Or is this the wrong question?  My end goal is a simple scrollable list of contacts and a user can choose a single contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `RecyclerView`. I think this is the best option when You load many items, in Your example contacts. RecyclerView is faster than a simple scroll view, it looks better, and has many many customization options. Useful docs:

1. [Create a List with RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)
2. [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView)

Good video explanation with an example:

1. [If You use Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vyqz_-sJGFk)
2. [If You use Kotlin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jo6Mtq7zkkg)